# Count operation with an inner join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a database

```
Employee
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
|  Fname   | Minit |  Lname    |  Emp_ID   | Sex  | Dept_num  |
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+
| John     | S     | Doe       | 123456789 | M    |         5 |
| Susan    | R     | Smith     | 333445555 | F    |         5 |
| Bob      | A     | Parker    | 999887777 | M    |         3 |
| Franklin | T     | Johnson   | 987654321 | M    |         4 |
| Debbie   | K     | Spencer   | 666884444 | F    |         3 |
| Stephen  | L     | English   | 453453453 | M    |         2 |
| Mary     | T     | Moore     | 987987987 | F    |         4 |
| James    | R     | Donaldson | 888665555 | M    |         1 |
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+------+-----------+

Works_on
+-----------+-----------+
|  Emp_ID   | Proj_num  |
+-----------+-----------+
| 123456789 |         1 |
| 123456789 |         2 |
| 666884444 |         3 |
| 453453453 |         1 |
| 453453453 |         2 |
| 333445555 |         2 |
| 333445555 |         3 |
| 333445555 |        10 |
| 333445555 |        20 |
| 999887777 |        30 |
| 999887777 |        10 |
| 987987987 |        10 |
| 987987987 |        30 |
| 987654321 |        30 |
| 987654321 |        20 |
| 888665555 |        20 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I have been doing some practice with some basic operations to see what they do in MySQL, but there is one that I am stuck on. Let's say I want to know the names of all employees that work on every project. They query should return an empty result since no employee works on projects 1, 2, 3, 10, 20, and 30.

What I tried to do what count the number of times each Emp_ID appeared in the works_on table. That would tell me the number of projects they were working on. For that I tried using the `COUNTS` method on Emp_ID. The query I tried running was this:

```
SELECT employee.Fname, employee.Minit, employee.Lname, 
COUNT(works_on.Emp_ID) AS Num_projects FROM works_on
INNER JOIN employee
ON works_on.emp_id=employee.emp_id
WHERE num_projects=6;
```

But I am getting an error since num_projects is an unknown column in the WHERE clause. I am brand new to SQL and have been reading a lot on websites like w3schools.com, and a lot of the examples on there are pretty straight forward and easy to understand, but something like this is a bit more complicated for a beginner.

My logic for this is that the query will go through and count how many times each Emp_ID appears in works_on. For instance, ID 333445555 appears 4 times in the table so the number of projects employee 333445555 works on is 4. I'm trying to get it to display the number of projects that each employee works on, and from there I can select the number that work on all, which like I said will be zero. Is the `COUNT` method the best way to do this, or would it be more appropriate to use a `DISTINCT`. I figured since `COUNT` returns the number of rows that matches the specified criteria, that this would be the correct operation to use.

Comment: Look into GROUP BY .. HAVING COUNT(*)=all projects

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: there is no `num_projects` column in your databases

Comment: @Strawberry pls check out the duplicate link

Comment: @Shadow I was not duplicating that post intentionally, but I am reading through it right now in hopes that I can get a better understanding of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @shadow I was too hasty I guess :-(

Comment: @Shadow The link you posted was able to help me answer my question! Thank you!

Comment: Don't worry about getting duplicate questions. The point is not to smack you for a duplicate, but to build a network of useful answers.  By the way, check this sql fiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5046bcd/2/0

Answer (score -2):

Watch out for case sensitivity in MySQL:

You have:

```
SELECT employee.Fname, employee.Minit, employee.Lname, 
COUNT(works_on.Emp_ID) AS Num_projects
```

Then:

```
WHERE num_projects=6;
```

Make sure that it's

```
WHERE Num_projects=6;
```

If you defined your AS as Num_projects, the where clause has to reference it exactly as Num_projects

Comment: Nope, this is not the solution.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to just add a comment Shadow, which I agree is more of what this is. Obviously this isn't the complete solution, but I wanted to give some feedback on the WHERE clause error. That's not encouraged?

Comment: What you wrote is not the cause for the unknown column error. Pls check out the duplicate link for the correct answer. Btw, if you meant this as a comment, then you simply should have avoided posting it as an answer. Posting comments as answers are not encouraged.